# Dell battery performs worse under Linux

Tags: battery

I have recently bought a Dell XPS Touch. I'm dual booting Windows 7 with Fedora 16 (Verne). Right out of the box, Fedora reports 1 hour 26 minutes of battery life at full charge, while Windows reports a whopping 4 hours!!

Why is this happening? Am I missing some `acpi` module or something?

A friend suggested to me that this could be due to the fact that I'm using `nouveau` instead of the proprietary `nvidia` driver. Does that sound reasonable?

**Update**

I am now on Debian Wheezy and still the issue persists. Removed Fedora tag.

Comment: Check if anything untowards is going on with [powertop](https://lesswatts.org/projects/powertop/).

Comment: Installed `powertop` and ran it. Things seem normal enough...

Comment: Battery all works bad in Linux, so not a dell specific problem.

Comment: That's a real bummer. But I had a different laptop with a similar setup and I don't recall such a large performance penalty. Is it a driver-specific thing? I was going to report that I tried battery life on a minimalist LFS (Linux from Scratch) build and I bumped again into this 2-hour mess. Is it kernel-inherent perhaps?

Comment: Nouveau has nothing like power management. @warl0ck, true, chromebooks/notebooks usually run out of power within 10 minutes... Jocking aside, Linux is not always as efficient as Windows when considering power management. Just keep in mind that Fedora and Windows are lying and try it yourself using the same protocol...  Same screen brightness, same HDD spin-down timeout, "same" drivers (nvidia) and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dell XPS seems to have an Nvidia hybrid (Optimus) graphics card. With correct driver setup, only the low-powered intel card is used, if you run more demanding applications, there's an automatic switch to the other card.

By default, this is not supported (to my knowledge) in linux systems, and this is why the power consumption is so high: it uses the full power all the time. There's a project called bumblebee, that adds support for such hybrids, so you can switch them on and off manually.

[Bumblebee Project](http://bumblebee-project.org/)

On my dell (not an XPS), this worked wonderfully and got me up to the expected five hours battery time.

Comment: +1 This helped but only _somehwat_. It upped my battery life by 50%. I'm accepting it since it seems to be the best way at the moment.

Comment: A recent discovery: I installed Fedora 20 on my Laptop (KDE, Bumblebee, nvidia drivers) and all I got out of it was a 3.5h battery time. It drained my machine at 18 W. I then installed the current Ubuntu GNOME edition (also using Bumblebee, nvidia drivers) and got 5.5 h from it, it using only 9 W. Somewhere between Fedora and KDE, something just eats up energy.

Answer (score 0):

Are the reported values realistic? If so, check how much your CPU is throttled e.g. in `/proc/cpuinfo` - if it doesn't run on lower frequencies without heavy load, it's just burning power for no reason (well, you could warm your breakfast on it). Adjusting display backlight might also help.

Comment: They are realistic in the sense that Fedora would suspend after the time it has reported and the BIOS reports a low battery when I try to power it back on. I tried `grep MHz /proc/cpuinfo` and all the cores seem to be running at 800 MHz at no load, which I'm guessing is quite alright. Adjusting backlight isn't really an option. Why should I limit my performance rather than fix the issue?

Comment: @JosephR. for it may be part of the issue. I would expect Windows to dim the backlight after some period of not being used (before suspending) or depending on ambient light, if you have recent enough hardware (which you do).

Comment: A friend suggested to me that this could be due to the fact that I'm using nouveau instead of the proprietary nvidia driver. Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: Good point, since the GPU in tablets are usually rather powerful. Do you have any desktop effects enabled?

Comment: Only the worst Desktop effect of all: Gnome3 :(
I will try an `awesome` session and see if it makes any difference to the battery life.

Comment: Can you switch to some other desktop - at least for testing? Something lighter like LXDE or XFCE?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. I will try a session on `awesome` when I get back home (I'm currently at work) and report back here.

Comment: Without desktop effects I would expect the difference between `nouveau` and `nvidia` much less important.

Comment: It made a difference alright. `awesome` reports 2 hours of battery life at full charge. I think this points to `nouveau`. Unfortunately, my current setup is critical for my workflow and I'm reluctant to mess with it. Will do so over winter break, hopefully.

Comment: @JosephR. Good luck!